# vba that will select not in common text

Tags: vba, excel

I Know how to build a loop macro to read all of the rows in a certain column, but what I do not know how to do is write it in such a way that it will select the data not in common and that may not sound correct so here is an excample:

```
column A
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

What I want is for the loop to look at column A but only the first row of the new data so it would look like this

```
Column A
1
2
3
```

Thank you,

Comment: Do you want the macro to simply delete duplicated values, leaving only the first instance??

Comment: You want to program a "delete duplicate" function ?

Comment: I want it to select and copy the data and paste it to another sheet so select 1 then 2 then 3 and past to another column on another sheet.

Comment: Don't need a macro, use the Advanced Filter feature to copy unique values

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
    A.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This will first copy to another sheet and then remove duplicates in the copy:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim A As Range, B As Range
    Set A = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
    Set B = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & A.Rows.Count)
    A.Copy B
    B.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: I want it to select and copy the data and paste it to another sheet so select 1 then 2 then 3 and past to another column on another worksheet.